# I'm getting error Object expected when trying to open a .js file

Tags: javascript

I am very green, so bear with me.

I am trying to open a .js file and am getting the following message.

Line: 4
Char: 1
Error: Object Expected
Code: 800A138F
Source: Microsoft JScript runtime error

Please see below for the full code.I have no idea what I need to add/change.  Thanks in advance.  I have left the comments in.

```
 * @fileOverview A sample script to demonstrate parallel collection runs using async.
 */
var path = require('path'), // ensures that the path is consistent, regardless of where the script is run from

    async = require('async'), // https://npmjs.org/package/async
    newman = require('../'), // change to require('newman'), if using outside this repository

    /**
     * A set of collection run options for the paralle collection runs. For demonstrative purposes in this script, an
     * identical set of options has been used. However, different options can be used, so as to actually run different
     * collections, with their corresponding run options in parallel.
     *
     * @type {Object}
     */
    options = {
        collection: path.join('C:\\Users\\conni\\Desktop', 'sample-collection.json')
    },

    /**
     * A collection runner function that runs a collection for a pre-determined options object.
     *
     * @param {Function} done - A callback function that marks the end of the current collection run, when called.
     */
    parallelCollectionRun = function (done) {
        newman.run(options, done);
    };

// Runs the Postman sample collection thrice, in parallel.
async.parallel([
    parallelCollectionRun,
    parallelCollectionRun,
    parallelCollectionRun
],

/**
 * The
 *
 * @param {?Error} err - An Error instance / null that determines whether or not the parallel collection run
 * succeeded.
 * @param {Array} results - An array of collection run summary objects.
 */
function (err, results) {
    err && console.error(err);

    results.forEach(function (result) {
        var failures = result.run.failures;

        console.info(failures.length ? JSON.stringify(failures.failures, null, 2) :
            '${result.collection.name} ran successfully.');
    });
});
```

Comment: this is a js file not an error

Comment: "I am trying to open a .js file" — How? With what JS compiler?

Comment: "getting the following message" — Is that the complete message? Normally I'd expect a line number at least.

Comment: Apologies, here are the error details:  Line: 4
Char: 1
Error: Object Expected
Code: 800A138F
Source: Microsoft JScript runtime error.   I am just double-clicking to open the file which I saved in notepad with a .js file extension

Comment: Why are you trying to run it with Microsoft JScript? The comments in the code mention Postman and NPM so I'd expect it is supposed to run inside Postman or Node.js (to access Postman externally). Did you get any instructions on how to use this piece of software? Do you know what it is supposed to do? (Some people double click executable files lurking around their computer while hoping they don't do anything destructive, that's generally a bad idea).

Comment: This is a part of a library, it has dependencies that you need to install. If you show me where you’re got this file from, I can help you to run it.

Comment: Double-clicking to open JS files is pretty much 100% of the time incorrect. You should read wherever you got the code from, they likely have usage instructions. You'll need to install *Node.js* and pass this file to Node from the command line at minimum.